# advice: efficient means of calculating the closet valid point on a 2d space

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry

I have a grid of squares which can have x,y points applied anywhere. However the only valid points are along the trajectory of knights-moves from 0,0 in any direction and distance (for instance 2x, y). There are other valid moves but for simplicity lets stick with this).

The problem I have been trying to get to grips with is, given Original point x,y how do I determine the closest valid point x,y?

So, for example if I had original point 1, 5 the closest valid point (visually on a graph) is 2,4 as it has the shortest physical distance

My amateur guess at how to do this would be to use pythagorus to calc each line length - but I suspects that with 100K+ calculations that this could be slow.

Is there a more efficient approach? - this will be in python

Comment: When you say trajectory of knight-moves do you mean continued repeats of the same move, rather than any valid knight-move from the new position? Do you know which knight-move trajectory to look along, or could it be any of them?

Comment: Good point - yes continued moves. My current thought is to step along the valid moves in a line, testing the distance from the current point (using pythagorus) to the original point each time. I should point out that my geometry and my python are rudimentary at best :)